# VB.NET Webbrowser, htmlelement getting a textbox by element that has no ID

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control

Using the code below I am logging into a website and then after I need to get the highlighted textbox in the picture. However, the textbox box does not have an id. How could I go about getting to the textbox to automate information input.[Google Inspection of the textbox element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VN86X.jpg)

Public Sub start_processing()

```
webBrowser1.Navigate("login to website passing credentials")

Do Until webBrowser1.ReadyState = WebBrowserReadyState.Complete
    Application.DoEvents()
Loop

webBrowser1.Navigate("https://secure.tmhp.com/TexMedConnect/EV/Default.aspx?pn=usercontrols/AcuteCare/EligibilityVerification")

Do Until webBrowser1.ReadyState = WebBrowserReadyState.Complete
    Application.DoEvents()
Loop

WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("fdosDatePicker").SetAttribute("Eligibility From Date", "11/22/2017")

'Also have been trying to get this to work but still cannot establish the input box

Dim allelements As HtmlElementCollection = webBrowser1.Document.All
For Each webpageelement As HtmlElement In allelements
    If webpageelement.GetAttribute("class") = "igte_TMCEditInContainer igte_TMCEditInContianer" Then
        MessageBox.Show("in if")
        webpageelement.SetAttribute("value", "example")
    End If
Next

end sub
```

Comment: Remove all the DoEvents, they are code smell. Also you can hook onto the `WebBrowser.DocumentCompleted` event and do your code in that. On a last note, above code doesnt reflect what you are trying to do, please update.

Comment: I removed the ASP.NET tag from your question. If you're using a `WebBrowser` control then it's a Windows Forms project, so nothing at all to do with ASP.NET.

Comment: You obviously have to know something about the input tag in order to be able to do anything with it. What do you know about it? You know it's an input tag for a start. Have you searched how to get access to input tags? What else do you know about it?

Comment: Hey guys thanks for the positive feedback. I have updated the code to illustrate what I am trying to do. Still pretty new to vb.net so please excuse my code smells @Codexer I tried it with if statements and the pages will not fully load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More or less what you were doing.

You can parse the  elements in you WebBrowser.Document, then set 
those you care about to a new value.

Here I suppose there are 1 or more Forms, which have a Submit button.
This is the standard. If in your case it's somewhat different, it's easily adjustable.

```
Dim _found As Boolean = False

If webBrowser1.Document.Forms.Count > 0 Then
   For Each _form As HtmlElement In _htmlpage.Forms

      'Get all <input> elements in the current Form
      Dim _inputs As HtmlElementCollection = _form.GetElementsByTagName("INPUT")

      'Start from the last element of the collection
      For x As Integer = _inputs.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1

         'A submit element has been found, so look for the "wanted" element
         If _inputs(x).GetAttribute("type") = "submit" Then
            For Each _input As HtmlElement In _inputs

              'When found, set its new value
               If _input.GetAttribute("class") = "igte_TMCEditInContainer" Then
                  _input.SetAttribute("value", "example")
                  _found = True
                  Exit For
               End If
            Next
            Exit For
         End If
      Next
      If _found = True Then Exit For
   Next
End If
```